# which code to change the background of a div-box?

Tags: css, background

Excuse me, I'm a complete nincompoop in php.
But there's this template I wanted to slightly change and I just can't find it. Can anyone save me?
The page is on http://markoleus.com/havahuy/
I wish to change the background of the sticky-header box containing the main menu (Home/Hans/Aanbod/...) to white.
(in order to always make the logo (on the left) be on white and thus come out better when i scroll).
In which file should I change which code?
Thanks for helping me out.

Marko

Comment: Please Post your code!

Answer (score 0):

In style.css look for .container or .for-sticky and add:

background-color: white;

In the future, use Chrome and left click on element, select "Inspect element" to locate the class you are looking to edit. :)

Comment: Dear Ezra,
I used your smart tip to 'Inspect Element' in Chrome for my next challenge: to lower the height of the top white window containing the logo and the menu.
The good news: I found <div id="undefined-sticky-wrapper" class="sticky-wrapper" style="height: 123px;">
The bad news: in which html or jss document is this line? Been looking all over, just can't spot it...
Can you help me out once more?

Answer (score -1):

[image]In CSS file add the following things:

```
.col-md-2
{
 background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
.col-md-10
{
 background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

This is how it will look.